# Finding the right directory to install applications into?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, user-account, disk-space, disk-format

I just downloaded the MS Teams app for MacOS and upon installation was asked if the app should be for all users/ current user/ installed on hard drive.

I understand the first two, but was wondering what is the difference between installing for all users and installing on the disk (I am using the pre-installed disk with no modifications).

If i install the app in the main disk, wouldn't it simply equate to installing for all users as the memory is shared?

[image: A screenshot showing the option to select a specific disk for installation]

Comment: Presumably, yes installing it on the hard drive would be the same as installing it for all users. This option would only really be useful if you had another separate hard drive.